# No Recommended Modules and Services on PrestaShop

Tags: web, content-management-system, prestashop, e-commerce

PrestaShop system don't show Recommended Modules and Services.
Console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

[image]

Comment: Make sure your server have outbound internet connection towards the prestashop domain (especially addons.prestashop.it)

Comment: How could I do that. I using Ampps with Apache Server.